# Doesn’t work the code Javascript inside echo in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've tried many times to solve this problem, when the option "OTROS" is selected it must show the div#contenedoropots but it doesn't work the script inside of echo PHP.

**PHP**

```
<option id="copiado"
  <?php 
    if($columna['tipo_defecto'] == "OTROS"){                            
        echo 'selected ';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';";
        echo "</script>";                                   
    } 
?>                  
        >OTROS</option>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contenedoropots" style="display:none">
     <label id="labelcopiarA" for="cpOtros">Especificar:</label>
     <input id="copiar" type="text" name="cpOtros"  onkeyup="copiarValue();" value="<?=$columna['especificar']?>"/>
</div>
```

The result with this code is in dropdown list:

```
document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';>OTROS
```

How can I get the script work in echo PHP.

Comment: `script` nested in `option` params

Comment: view source in browser and you'll see your syntax error (if you know html)

Comment: `script` works in browser, not in PHP. In this case it's just echo'ed inside an `option` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current otput produces invalid html-tags, try to add the javascript after you clsed any open option-element and better even after you closed the select-element.

```
<option id="copiado" <?php 
    if($columna['tipo_defecto'] == "OTROS"){                            
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    } 
?>>OTROS</option>

<!-- complete the html-elements (options, select), then output the javascript if needed -->

<?php
    if($columna['tipo_defecto'] == "OTROS"){                            
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';";
        echo "</script>";                                   
    } 
?>
```